# Does jsf support ES6 modules?

Tags: jsf

I tried to include some simple javascript code in my JSF page.
Works ok but problems begin including javascript code with modules functionalities.

in file myLib.js:

```
import { tag } from '/primefaces-crud-1.1/resources/js/html.js';
```

in file button.xhtml:

```
<h:outputScript library="js" name="myLib.js" />
```

console error:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token {
>   main.js:42 in Startnull

￼
​

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow :D Please show your main.js code. There could be an error on line 42. Could also be that there is an error somewhere in your module causing this error. Short answer, it could be anything right now! A bit more information could help you gain more interest from other developers to answer this.

Comment: Well...I don't have main.js. I have simple xhtml (jsf).

Comment: JSF has no knowledge of ES6 modules (nor should it afaik...).  And if you don't have a main.js, why is there an error in that file according to your own post?

Comment: Well...I don't have main.js. I have simple xhtml (jsf). And I try to include some custom javascript code. Yes, should not mix it, but I try to check some jsf and ES6 functionalities. I suspect that there is an error parsing jsf page. JSF page and  JS code without modules works as expected. I'm using WildFly 15 AS.

Comment: In delveloper console/sources I have: /primefaces-crud-1.1/javax.faces.resource/myLib.js.xhtml?ln=js
And part with:  import { tag } from '/primefaces-crud-1.1/resources/js/html.js'; is marked with error "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token {"

Comment: So maybe your browser does not support it? And you can edit your question to add relevant info like in your comment

Comment: I doubt it's browser support. I use latest chrome browser: Version 74.0.3729.108 (Official Build) (64-bit). And simple HTML page with same ES6 code works just fine. It must be some jsf part missing in my code but I just can't find it. Thank you for your  time & comments.

Comment: Did you find a solution for this problem? I am able to import normal JS functions just fine but Module functions do not seem to work?